# A variation of Birkhoff's Ergodic theorem

Tags: probability, ergodic-theory

Suppose $T_k$ are measure perserving for each $k$, and $f$ is integrable. Is it true that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(T_k\circ T_{k-1}\dots\circ T_1 \omega)$ converge almost surely?